# Securing UDP - OpenSSL or GnuTls or ...?

Tags: linux, security, udp, openssl

I need to secure my UDP traffic. As far as I understand DTLS protocol is the best way to do it. There is another one  - IPsec - but it looks not applicable for me because it's not easy to use and there are possible hardware problems.

I've found that there are some libraries which have DTLS implemented. So now I'm trying to choose - OpenSSL or GnuTls? Could you please advise me what is better to use? What are drawbacks or advantages? Or may be there is another library with DTLS support implemented?

Comment: What platform / language / development tool are you targeting?

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski I'm using C/GCC/Linux now, maybe Windows later.

Comment: many guy at openldap have problem with gnutls, and they suggest to use openssl. You may check this link http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201202/msg00379.html for more

Comment: In terms of security, I believe that OpenSSL has a pretty poor track record, and GNUtls a bit less poor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found the following facts about the libraries and DTLS.

1. There is another lib with DTLS support - CyaSSL, but it supports DTLS only in test mode for now.
2. Although RFC 4347 dates from Apr, 2006, the OpenSSL supports DTLS since 2005 (v0.9.8). Many Linux distribs include this version. OpenSSL API looks ugly a little, but it seems like DTLS implementation is stable.
3. GnuTls supports DTLS since 2011 (v3.0.0). Looks like no Linux includes this version yet. (For example, Ubuntu 11.04 uses v2.8.6, Ubuntu 11.10 is going to use v2.10.5, not v3.0.0.) There is no information about when v3.0 will be used. It can be built manually, however it depends on too many additional libraries which may have no native support in some distribs.
4. It looks like all of these libraries can be used on other platforms (e.g. Windows).
5. Known OpenSSL issue: OpenSSL has compression enabled by default for DTLS, but it shouldn't be. OpenSSL v0.9.8 API doesn't provide any method to disable compression. The method should be implemented manually.

SUMMARY:

Speaking about usability, personally I would prefer GnuTls API, but at the time OpenSSL looks more preferable to use.

Comment: Don't forget to check the licenses and make sure that you are using one which has a license that works for you.

Answer (score 5):

IPsec is the oldest and hence most compatible and stable, but requires tasks from the sysadmin and can be quite challenging for novices.  DTLS is tackling the problem from the application side which the programmer can significantly simplify and integrate with existing environments with less change.

The choice between OpenSSL and GnuTLS is almost always due to license.

OpenSSL license includes an advertising clause:

> 3. All advertising materials mentioning features or use of this  * 
>   software must display the following acknowledgment:  *    "This
>   product includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project  *    for
>   use in the OpenSSL Toolkit. (http://www.openssl.org/)"

GnuTLS from Wikipedia:

> GnuTLS was initially created to allow applications of the GNU project
>   to use secure protocols such as TLS. Although OpenSSL already existed,
>   OpenSSL's license is not compatible with the GPL;[4] thus software
>   under the GPL, such as GNU software, could not use OpenSSL without
>   making a GPL linking exception.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GnuTLS

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know any issues with RFC 4347 compliance, platform compatibility or specific bugs?